# Stuck on making Android apps with NetBeans, missing functions I normally love

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans

I've followed the tutorial link below, so to create an android project within Netbeans but I can't find the design view even when I click on the XML files. Am I missing something?

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/dummy_guide_to_netbeans_android

Any tutorials explaining this would be great `:-)`

*The reason I would rather use Netbeans over Eclipse, is that netbeans allows the use of a pallet to drag "buttons" or "listbox-es" over to the design view. And on click open up the buttons functions i.e. "on click" or "on item state change"*

Comment: Eclipse has all of that functionality. http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlpfU.png

Comment: use android studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans does not have an android layout preview function like in Eclipse. You will have to install a plug-in located here:

http://www.nbandroid.org

Any version published after October 2012 will enable you to have the feature you are looking for.